# Angular JS $http.get add [] at the end of JSON string

Tags: json, angularjs

When I try to parse JSON from URL through `$http.get` I get a strange `[]` at the end of the string.

The URL I am using is:

http://tol.vpo.si/json/fetchCategories/

and the code:

```
 $http.get('http://tol.vpo.si/json/fetchCategories/',
            {
                cache: false,
                transformResponse: function (data, headersGetter) {
                    console.log(data);
                    try {
                        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data); // verify that json is valid
                        return jsonObject;
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        console.log("did not receive a valid Json: " + e)
                    }
                    return {};
                }
            }
        ).then(function(resp) {
            $scope.categories= resp.data;
        }, function(err) {
           console.log(err)
        });
```

The answer:

```
console.log:
[{"ID":"69","IME":"ANALISI TECNICA","D1":"al"},{"ID":"375","IME":"PRIMO PIANO","D1":"prp"}][]
```

> did not receive a valid Json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

The URL went succesfully through JSON validation.

Is it possible it is server issue?

Comment: Just try `$http.get(url).then(function(response) { console.log(response.data); });`

Comment: Because it's a javascript array of objects and not a JSON object.

Comment: array (url) is built with php json_encode()

Answer (score 0):

Check this working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmfnhvL/1/).

By comparing the request headers from the `$http` request and a normal request from browsers, I found the difference in header field `Accept`. If not specify `Accept`, the field is `Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*`. Add this code makes the returned data correct:

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
},
```

Seems the magic option is `text/html`. Keep only this value makes it working.

Comment: weird. i refreshed it maybe 40 times, never getting the extra []

Comment: Your JS doesn't always report error, right? Just now I visited with `https` and browse back, the format was incorrect. But not cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @AleksanderPetrov My pleasure. Please kindly upvote/accept :)